# While using a material.textfield.TextInputLayout, my outlined box covers the hint. How can I display the hint without getting it covered my the box?

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

[image]

As you can see in the image, I am using a material textInputEditText with an outlined Box style. However, my hint 'Exchange' is getting covered by the outlined box. How can I prevent that?

Here is my textfield.TextInputLayout code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Exchange_Name"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    android:paddingTop="32dp"
    style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle">

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="@string/Exchange"
          android:inputType="text">

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
```

And here is my styles.xml-

```
    <style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">#FF6F9824</item>

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `android:paddingTop="32dp"` in your `TextInputLayout`.
Also the hint should be set on `TextInputLayout`, rather than the `TextInputEditText`.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:hint="@string/Exchange"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Exchange_Name"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
    >
```

[image]